# Simulink MultiArray message generation to ROS

Tags: matlab, message, simulink, ros

How can I create a publisher that in **Simulink (Matlab R2015A)** that sends an array of floats as a **ROS message** (in ROS Indigo under Ubuntu 14.04)? I should use the `BlankMSG` block with msg type: `std_msgs/Float32MultiArray`, a `Publish` block with the same msg type and my own topic name.

I don't know how to add the vector to the data field on the msg bus. I tired, with a `Bus Assignment` block where the data input is a constant vector, but I get an error:

> The Bus input port of the Bus Assignment block 'SubscriberMotorStates/Bus Assignment' does not support an array of buses as a sub-element.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried in Matlab to send an array and did work by following the [instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rospublisher.html).

```
chatpub = rospublisher('/chatter','std_msgs/Float64MultiArray');
msg = rosmessage(chatpub);
msg.Data = [1 2 3];
send(chatpub,msg);
```

So, I can also use in simulink this by implementing a function in an *.m file and use the `Interpreted MATLAB function` block.

I'm still curious how can I use the intended blocks for array message sending, because it might be better optimized. (I'm going to use in a real application)

Comment: have you tried to do it by hand in a matlab function instead of using the bus assignment block?

Comment: I tried in MatLab and it works just following the instructions online. Edit in original post.

Comment: The problem is the `Bus Assignment` block. Just replace it with a `MATLAB Function` one which manually handles the wiring. It should be fine.